# How to handle JSON parsing errors using EventEmitter in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm developing a module in Node.js and using EventEmitter to stream data from an application that is emitting JSON. I want to handle JSON parsing errors correctly.

Ex 1: Use try/catch block and pass SyntaxError to message event callback

```
let buffer = '';
stream.on('data', data => {
  buffer += data;
  let boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n');
  while (boundary !== -1){
    const input = buffer.substring(0, boundary);
    buffer = buffer.substring(boundary + 1);
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(input);
      this.emit('message', json);
    } catch (err) {
      this.emit('message', err, null);
    }
    boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n');
  }
});
```

Ex 2: Use try/catch block and emit error event, pass SyntaxError to error event callback

```
let buffer = '';
stream.on('data', data => {
  buffer += data;
  let boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n');
  while (boundary !== -1){
    const input = buffer.substring(0, boundary);
    buffer = buffer.substring(boundary + 1);
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(input);
      this.emit('message', json);
    } catch (err) {
      this.emit('error', err);
    }
    boundary = buffer.indexOf('\n');
  }
});
```

Is there a preferred convention for handling these types of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions are defendable but in term of Node.js EventEmitter convention I think solution 2 is better.

If you refer to the documentation : https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_eventname_args all emit() args are just additional arguments nothing about error handling.

I guess you'll have to implement a generic 'error' listener and switch between error cases to handle them individually or by default.